# To create multiple data frames from multiple excel files using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have many excel files in a folder.
The task is to read these excel files as individual data frames using a loop and merge them according to key inserted by the user. I was able to get the names of the files in a list `file_list`.
How to iterate over list to load excel files as individual dataframes?

```
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\RPA")

file_list= []

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\RPA"):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.xlsx'):
            file_list.append(file)
print(file_list)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `key`? Can you give us an example?

Comment: A column name that exists in both dataframes, used for joining data frames in pandas

Answer (score 0):

Use the `glob` module for simple recursive traversal and parsing-

```
import glob
import pd
files = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\RPA\\**\\*.xlsx',recursive = True)
excel_dfs = []
for f in files:
  df = pd.read_excel(f)
  excel_dfs.append(df)
```

Comment: i want to store .xlsx files as df1,df2 etc.hence it can be passed to function.

Comment: You can iterate over the 'files' list and use pandas.read_excel() to capture each of the file as dataframe.

Comment: c=pd.DataFrame()
for file in df_dict:
    c=pd.read_excel(file)
    print (c)''' i can print the files stored.what is the names of dataframes stored?Hence i can pass it as arguments to function

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the list of file names you can do something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()

for file in file_list:
  this_df = pd.read_excel(file)
  if len(this_df) == 0:
    df = this_df
  else:
    df = pd.merge(left=df, right=this_df, how="inner", left_on="key", right_on="key")
```

Comment: i get the error on the key. KeyError: 'Manager'.

Comment: You need to change the `left_on` and `right_on` based on the key selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\RPA'
d=[]
d = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
print(d)
df= []
for file in d:
    c=pd.read_excel(file)
    df.append(c)
df1 = pd.merge(*df, how="inner", on="Manager")
print(df1)
```